# postgre version per rails branch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to use a specific snapshot of the database, per each branch (git) that I have?

Reason for this is, the table definition will change because of the need per each branch that I'm working on.

The web framework I'm using is rails 4 by the way. Postgresql 9.5.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is possible to have a database per branch. you can find more information here [rails database per branch](http://manas.com.ar/blog/2016/01/08/switching-rails-app-database-per-git-branch.html) or [git rails database branch hook](https://github.com/room118solutions/git-rails-database-branch-hook)

Comment: I ended up not using this, but yes this is the answer. Thank you @shani